# Need to change multiple values across multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, subset, recode

I have 72 variables that indicate whether or not a child is able to read 72 words. The variables are actually coded as `""` (empty), `"!"`, and `"1"` to indicate, respectively, whether the child got the word *correct*, *not reached*, or *incorrect*. Values are coded as strings. This is an extract of the tibble

```
lit <- data.frame(rbind(c("1", "", "", ""),
           c("", "1", "1", "1"),
           c("!", "", "", ""),
           c("!", "", "", "")))

lit
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1         
2     1  1  1
3  !         
4  !
```

I need to recode them as `1`, `NA` and `0` respectively to perform some statistics (e.g. individual count of word correct, means, etc.). I am expecting the following output:

```
lit
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  0
3 NA  1  1  1
4 NA  1  1  1
```

I tried the following code

```
for(k in words) {
if(lit[[k]][lit[[k]] == ""]){
    lit[[k]][lit[[k]]] <- 1
  }
  else {lit[[k]][lit[[k]]] <- 0
     }}
```

where `words` is actually a vector with the names of variables I need to recode. In the `for` loop you see coded here, I would be happy to recode only correct words as 1 and all the rest as 0, although the option with `NA` would be preferred.

After running the `for` loop, I got the following message:

```
Error in if (lit[[k]][lit[[k]] == ""]) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (lit[[k]][lit[[k]] == ""]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help is much appreciated, especially if using `dplyr`, which I am currently trying to improve

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to read about [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, a sample of your data, or similar fake data, would be useful. Try using `dput`.

Comment: thank you @h-1, this works perfectly. one more questions, how can I subset the columns I want to mutate, in case I do not need to mutate all of them? I have variables like age and gender that I want to keep as they are

Comment: Use `mutate_at(vars(-age, -gender), ~c(1, NA, 0)[match(.x, c("", "!", "1"))])`.

Comment: I get an error `Error in eval(variables_names, envir = envir, enclos = baseenv()) : 
  object 'age' not found`. I piped your code after `lit`

Comment: After checking the help files for `mutate_at` and several trials and errors, I finally managed to run the code successfully. `mutate_at` requires the variables as a character vector of column names. So my final code was something like that `lit %>%  mutate_at(c("var_1",  "var_2", "...",  "var_n"), ~c(1, NA, 0)[match(.x, c("", "!", "1"))])`

Comment: @Manolo - glad you got it working.  However, it is not correct that `mutate_at()` requires a character vector of names.  As in my example above, you can pass unquoted expressions by wrapping with the `vars()` function.  This will also permit you to use tidyselect helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the results of `match()` to index a vector of the replacement values.

```
library(dplyr)

lit %>%
  mutate_all(~c(1, NA, 0)[match(.x, c("", "!", "1"))])  

  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  0
3 NA  1  1  1
4 NA  1  1  1
```